# Is there a way to recursively subset a dataframe and assign the new dataframes to a unique variable name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to make an Rmarkdown script that can be as 1-click as possible for broader use at my company. I'm reading in a csv file with 4 columns and 20 rows. I want to subset this dataframe into other dfs based on a value in 1 column and name the new dfs 'df_value1', 'df_value2', and so on.

I'm trying to copy the functionality of this block:

```
df <- read.csv("data_template", header = TRUE)

df_0000 <- subset.data.frame(df, subset = ID == '0000')
df_1111 <- subset.data.frame(df, subset = ID == '1111')
```

So far I have this:

```
IDs = unique(data$ID)
IDs = list(IDs)

for (i in IDs[[1]]){
  i = subset.data.frame(data, subset = ID == i)
}
```

Which I'm sure you can tell, just ends up with variable i storing a df that is the right output but has all the data from the last value in the list.

I imagine that I'll want to store the ID `'i'` in a `str` variable and then iteratively name the df but I don't know how to access the data stored in the variable without reassigning the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column that identifies the dataframes is in a column called mygroups, then you could use `dplyr` [group_split](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html)

```
library(dplyr)

my_list_of_dfs <- df %>% 
   group_by(mygroups) %>%
   group_split()
```

and access each dataframe by using normal list notation.

```
my_list_of_dfs[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
df_list = split(df, df$ID)
```